# How to add 5 minutes to my current time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got current Time like that. also i need it as string

```
  var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
  var selectedTime = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

How to add 3 minutes to this time?

Comment: [Add Days, Months or Years to Current Date in Swift](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/add-days-months-or-years-to-current-date-in-swift/) - it's no "minutes", but you should the idea

Comment: [How to work with dates and times in Swift 3, part 4: Adding Swift syntactic magic](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/08/30/how-to-work-with-dates-and-times-in-swift-3-part-4-adding-swift-syntactic-magic/) has a rather neat idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 3, to: Date())
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
var selectedTime = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

Comment: thanks! This is the correct answer thanks bro